# use EAR lib instead of WAR lib in Jboss

Tags: jboss

I'm using jboss application server. When I deployed an EAR in jboss, it uses the WAR lib instead of EAR lib, so can anyone tell me how I can specify in jboss to use EAR lib instead of WAR lib.

note: I'm using jboss 4.2.3.GA

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually the answer but rather an opinion.

I remember the old project with java, when I deploy the EAR file directly, some of my function like upload doesn't work. When I check in the tmp folder. All of my data is currently there. So if you turn off the computer those data would be gone.

So another way to do it, is to extract the EAR file manually to JAR and WAR then you deploy them. I would work fine.

And that is the Jboss 5.1 actually.